# Why use self class in java with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Is it a rule to use self class in the self.methods with or without Spring?
For example, I have

```
public class MyClass{
    private Class1 class1;
    private Class2 class2;
    private MyClass self;

    public void myMethod(){

        self.makeThing();
    }

    public void makeThing(){}
}
```

So, why don't just make `makeThing()` instead `self.makeThing()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the context of Spring, you need to inject a bean into itself if you want to trigger AOP classes.

```
class MyClass {
   @Resource
   MyClass self;

   public void doSomething() {
       // This will NOT trigger the AOP associated with @SomeAnnotation
       this.doSomethingElse();

       // This will trigger the AOP associated with @SomeAnnotation
       self.doSomethingElse();
   }

   @SomeAnnotation
   public void doSomethingElse() {
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: @Mr.J4mes, so why does it need to use AOP in self? I understand about AOP in other classes, but in self...

Comment: The why is particular to your own business logic in each application. Most of the time, you will call a method from another class but when you do need to call another method from the same class with some AOP capabilities, this is the way to do. For example, in my application, I created a custom annotation called `@Memoize` to cache the result of some method calls. So I need to call my methods using `self` in order to get the cached results.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes, Do you use your own cache with only annotation? Because I need to use cache and it needs to use xmemcache or other library

Comment: In my application, I implemented a request-level cache using my own annotation because I cannot use application-level cache due to some restrictions of the production environment. However, if it's possible for you to use application-level cache, you can certainly use xmemcache, Hazelcast, EHCache or any other libraries :). Your cache will be available across requests which is better for performance than a request-level cache.

Comment: Btw this is only required if you use the spring-aop instead of a full blown AOP library like AspectJ.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I've never had a need for AspectJ so I cannot give you a definite answer. However, from my understanding, Spring make use of runtime weaving to implement AOP capabilities via Spring proxy. This is why you need to inject a class into itself in order to have your method calls go through the AOP proxy. As for AspectJ, they're using compile-time and classload-time weaving. It might be possible to work with `this`. You'd need to read more to verify that though :)